# <a-sound> does not kick start when marker is detected

Tags: image, audio, aframe

I am very new to java script and html, and I am so stack with this.
The following is what I wrote and wanted to  primitive to start when the marker is detected.
However, the sound start as soon as when I access the html on a browser.

```
   <a-marker type="pattern" url="pat/ban.patt">
      <a-entity>
         <a-image id="obj0" rotation="-90 0 0" src="#banto" width="5" height="5"></a-image>
         <a-entity position="-0.75 1 1" rotation="-90 0 0" text-geometry="value: Head of the cleark; bevelEnabled: false; bevelSize: 0.008; bevelThickness: 0.08; size: 0.25;" material="color: cyan;"></a-entity>
         <a-sound src="#bantoSound" autoplay="true"></a-sound>
      </a-entity>
    </a-marker>
```

Although the  is shown only when the marker is detected....

Does not  work as same as ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the `autoplay:true` fires the sound whenever the entity is loaded in the DOM.

I suggest You disable autoplay, or stop all sounds when the scene loads, and You activate it when the marker is visible:

```
if(document.querySelector("a-marker").object3D.visible == true){
  // play the sound
}
```